# How do I set the field variables in a method to data being read in from a .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I have my default constructor set to at the moment.

```
//Default constructor
public MyInfo(String args) {
    Name = "";
    DateOfBirth = "";
    Location = "";
    AvgTemp = 0;
}
```

Comment: okay so make it `public MyInfo(String name, String date, String loc, int av)` and then once reading in the text file make new objects with the values in the file

Comment: ...or start by reading any intro to Java text book. This is 1st chapter stuff that you're posting here.

Comment: I have a main class that I am reading the .txt file into first. From that data I need to set my constructor values to what is in the .txt. file.    info = new MyInfo(args[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure what your actual .txt file looks like im going to assume that each line has Name,DateOfBirth,Location,AvgTemp.

Using a buffered reader, read the lines within a while loop and assign each value in an array after splitting the line by commas for example. Make sure to change your current variables to arrays before doing this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Filename.txt"));
while (somevariable!=null){
somevairable=br.readLine();
String[] parts = somevariable.split(",");
Names[x]=parts[1]
```

And I will leave the rest up to you. Hopefully this is a decent start and you can follow the instructions. I suggest reading up on different types of file and buffered readers and writers.